# how to center showMenu in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-dependencies

How can I make the message show in the center on any kind of screen. I've tried but it does not work properly by entering values but that is not responsive in all screens.

```
    void _showPopupMenu4() async{
    await showMenu(
    context: context,
    position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(220, 80, 0, 500),
      items: [
        ///2nd item delete button
        PopupMenuItem(
          onTap: () {
            title.value = 'Delete';
          },
          child: Row(
            children: [
              const Icon(
                Icons.delete_outline,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(52, 107, 33, 1),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 15),
              Text(
                'Delete',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              const Icon(
                Icons.qr_code_scanner_rounded,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(52, 107, 33, 1),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 15),
              Text(
                'Scan QR Code',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
      elevation: 4.0,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MediaQuery` widget to get the size of the screen and then calculate the position of the popup menu accordingly

**Code:**

```
void _showPopupMenu4() async{
  final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

  final RenderBox overlay = Overlay.of(context)!.context.findRenderObject()!;

  final menuWidth = 150.0;
  final menuHeight = 100.0;

  final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

  final position = RelativeRect.fromSize(
    Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: menuWidth, height: menuHeight),
    size,
  );

  await showMenu(
    context: context,
    position: position,
    items: [
      ///2nd item delete button
      PopupMenuItem(
        onTap: () {
          title.value = 'Delete';
        },
        child: Row(
          children: [
            const Icon(
              Icons.delete_outline,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(52, 107, 33, 1),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 15),
            Text(
              'Delete',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            const Icon(
              Icons.qr_code_scanner_rounded,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(52, 107, 33, 1),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 15),
            Text(
              'Scan QR Code',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
    elevation: 4.0,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    color: Colors.white,
    captureInheritedThemes: false,
    captureInheritedWidgetsWithNullTheme: true,
    useRootNavigator: false,
    semanticsDismissible: false,
    // This is important to make the menu background transparent
    barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
    // This is important to make the menu take up the whole screen
    // instead of being constrained to the context area.
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  );
}
```